# Authentication with Firebase in React Native apps

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a React Native App in which I use Firebase for database and authentication. I use custom authentication with Firebase where I generate a token on my server side code and pass on the token to the client and the client authenticates itself using `signInWithCustomToken` method. Earlier, we could specify an expiry period for the token and I could use the same token again and again. This was then changed in a later version to have an expiry period of one hour after being issued and it was mentioned that the Firebase SDK will make sure to maintain connections and the user wouldn't need to do the authentication again and again. I recently saw that in [v3.6.2](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.6.2), there was some fixes to the authentication for react native

> Fixed an issue that prevented user authentication states from
>   persisting when using Firebase Authentication with React Native
>   versions 0.37 and higher.

I am using the latest `v3.6.6` at the moment. I still see that the user is authenticated every now and then when the app is foregrounded. I wanted to know how does authentication with firebase in react native apps work. The user will put the app in the background at which point it would be suspended by the phone OS or even killed in some conditions. When the user put the app in foreground again, should I expect that the Firebase SDK would make sure that the connection to firebase stays on or would it authenticate with firebase again?

Comment: The token should only refresh when the app is in the foreground. If the app is relaunched or resumed, you should remain authenticated. If you detect otherwise, notify Firebase group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk